# C# Task rewrite function with custom task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a function that was declared like this:

```
public Task<PossibleUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    Task<PossibleUser> task = context.TabelaStudenti.Where(
        apu => apu.NrMatricol == userName)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return task;
}
```

The problem is that **I want to return something else from that function now**, for example, I tried:

```
 public Task<PossibleUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        Student studentUser = context.TabelaStudenti.Where(st => st.NrMatricol == userName).FirstOrDefault();
        Task<PossibleUser> someTask= new Task<PossibleUser>(() =>
        {
            if (studentUser == null)
            {
                return new PossibleUser()
                {
                    Password = studentUser.Parola,
                    UserName = studentUser.UserName
                };
            }
            else
            {
                //just return something else
                return new PossibleUser();
            }
        });
    return someTask;
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I get no response from that function.
**How could I modify the first function in order to return my own custom task?**

I have to specify that this function is already called like this:

```
PossibleUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
```

and it is a part of ASP.NET Web API Owin Authentication, where UserManager is

```
    UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<PossibleUser>(new StudentStore()) { PasswordHasher = new MyPasswordHasher() };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply forget to start you newly created task:

```
public Task<PossibleUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    Student studentUser = context.TabelaStudenti.Where(st => st.NrMatricol == userName).FirstOrDefault();
    Task<PossibleUser> someTask= new Task<PossibleUser>(() =>
    {
        if (studentUser == null)
        {
            return new PossibleUser()
            {
                Password = studentUser.Parola,
                UserName = studentUser.UserName
            };
        }
        else
        {
            //just return something else
            return new PossibleUser();
        }
    });

    // start your task
    someTask.Start();
    return someTask;
}
```

Or since C# compiler is smart enough you can just directly return `PossibleUser` from code:

```
 public async Task<PossibleUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
 {
    Task<PossibleUser> task = context.TabelaStudenti.Where(apu => apu.NrMatricol == userName)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    // get result from async method
    var studentUser = await task;

    if (studentUser == null)
    {
        // Direct return without creating Task
        return new PossibleUser()
        {
            Password = studentUser.Parola,
            UserName = studentUser.UserName
        };
    }
    else
    {
        //just return something else
        return new PossibleUser();
    }
    return someTask;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never use the task constructor. Just use `async`/`await`:

```
public async Task<PossibleUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
  Student studentUser = await context.TabelaStudenti.FirstOrDefaultAsync(st => st.NrMatricol == userName);
  if (studentUser != null)
  {
    return new PossibleUser()
    {
      Password = studentUser.Parola,
      UserName = studentUser.UserName
    };
  }
  else
  {
    //just return something else
    return new PossibleUser();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) something like this:

```
public Task<PossibleUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
{
    return context.TabelaStudenti
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(st => st.NrMatricol == userName)
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            var studentUser = task.Result;
            if (studentUser != null)
            {
                return new PossibleUser
                {
                    Password = studentUser.Parola,
                    UserName = studentUser.UserName
                };
            }
            //just return something else
            return new PossibleUser();
        });
}
```